# Ruby regex ‘backslash R’ aka ‘\R’ pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I am pretty sure I have seen *“`\R` was introduced in Ruby2 to match newlines, despite where they came from: unix `\n`, macos `\r` or windows `\r\n`”* somewhere. That said, Ruby2 should treat `\R` like `%r{\r\n|\r|\n}`.

This works fine:

```
▶ "a\nb".match /\R/
#⇒ #<MatchData "\n">
▶ "a\rb".match /\R/
#⇒ #<MatchData "\r">
▶ "a\r\nb".match /\R/
#⇒ #<MatchData "\r\n">
```

even whether line endings/feeds are combined:

```
▶ "a\r\n\nb".match /\R{2}/
#⇒ #<MatchData "\r\n\n">
```

unless one tries to negate `\R`:

```
▶ "a\nb".match /[^\R]+/
#⇒ #<MatchData "a\nb">
```

Negating `\n` works fine though:

```
▶ "a\nb".match /[^\n]+/
#⇒ #<MatchData "a">
```

Unfortunately, `\R` is enormously hard to google. Neither [`Regexp` rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html) nor [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) have a mention of it.

Would any regex guru drop an explanation here, so that it was at least easily googled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After reading @sawa's explanation, which seems perfectly reasonable, I'm wondering if this could be a bug.  It seems to me that `"a\nb".match /[^\R]+/` should work the way you expected. I dropped an email to [K. Takata](https://github.com/k-takata) asking that he/she have a look at your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for that. On the other hand, I don’t think that the disjunction of atomic expressions could be [easily] negated. We simply should not expect the correct behaviour inside square brackets from non-literals, exactly as we don’t expect backward references (having apparently almost the same notation) to act properly inside character grouping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the author: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE#L101. It says

```
\R       Linebreak

         Unicode:
           (?>\x0D\x0A|[\x0A-\x0D\x{85}\x{2028}\x{2029}])

         Not Unicode:
           (?>\x0D\x0A|[\x0A-\x0D])
```

What seems relevant here to your question is that it is not a character group, but is a list of alternatives. Given that the sequence is not necessarily a single character, I guess it could not be made into a character group. This is probably interacting in peculiar way with negation, which is intended to be used only with characters and/or character groups.

Comment: Thank you, this reference is exactly what I missed. Would you mind to update your reference to include line anchor: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE#L101